# PayPal adaptive payments returnUrl parameters

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using the adaptive payments API by first issuing a Pay request with actionType=CREATE and I was wondering if it is possible that PP will redirect the user to my site with the pay_key as GET parameter?

This is what PP does with ExpressCheckout API and I was wondering if this can also happen with adaptive payments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the PayPal specification for ExpressCheckout API and Adaptive Payments API. In case of the ExpressCheckout, PayPal returns the token with the ReturnURL after the user is sent to PayPal for checkout authorization. (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/ec/SandboxECUX.gif).

In case of Adaptive Payments API PayPal does NOT send the token with the ReturnURL after the user makes the authorization (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/ap/AdapPymntSrvcFlow_A.gif)

In any case, the token retrieved in the SetExpressCheckout (for ExpressCheckouts) or Pay (for adaptive payments) can be saved in session for later usage if needed.

Comment: I'm not sending the user but PayPal does redirect him to authorize the payment. Is it possible to get the pay_key with the returnUrl?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do but when you make the Pay request using actionType=CREATE you can also specify as a paremeter of the request the "returnUrl". You make the request, PayPal answers you with a token and then you send the user to PayPal with that token.

Comment: I ended up storing the pay_key and retrieving it for later API calls.
AP is quite different than ExpressCheckout API where PP sends back the token as a GET parameter on the returnUrl.

Comment: In case of ExpressCheckout, you get the token with the ReturnURL like you pointed out. The token is the same that get the when you make the SetExpressCheckout so you basically do not need this token.

Any way, in the case of the Pay Request you don't get the token back with the ReturlURL because the process is done (payment completed or cancel) and you cannot use the token again. If for some reason you really need you can always store it in your session when you get it for the first time.

Comment: This is not 100% correct, you can split the Pay request into 2 messages: first Pay with actionType=CREATE and then ExecutePayment API to finalize the payment.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was thinking in actionType=Pay.
In case of actionType=CREATE you can make the ExecutePayment call afterwards. Still, you don't need the token in the ReturnURL. You can just save it in session before sending the user to paypal.

Comment: To be more specific. If you look at the picture:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/ap/AdapPymntSrvcFlow_A.gif
Before doing step 3 you can just save the token and use it for later usage.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing.

Comment: Then the answer to your question is just "no", agree?

Comment: Yes, update your answer based on our findings and I will accept your answer.